# Python Generator Behavior

Tags: python, generator, coroutine

What am I misunderstanding about generators, that I'm not getting the output I'm expecting? I'm trying to create a simple function that will output whatever data i .send() it, or return 'none' if no information is sent.

```
import pudb
#pudb.set_trace()
def gen():
        i = 0
        while True:
                val = (yield i)
                i = val
                if val is not None:
                        yield val
                else:
                        yield 'none'

test = gen()
next(test)
print test.send('this')
print test.send('that')
print test.next()
print test.send('now')
```

Expected output:

```
'this'
'that'
'none'
'now'
```

Actual output:

```
'this'
'this'
'none'
'none'
```

Comment: When posting questions, please make sure that the code you've posted actually produces the output you've posted. When run, this code produces output with no quote characters, and the last output is capitalized, since you're printing the actual `None` object instead of `'none'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You yield each value twice. Once here:

```
val = (yield i)
```

and once here:

```
yield val
```

You should only yield each value once, and capture the user's input, like so:

```
def parrot():
    val = None
    while True:
        val = yield val
```

If you really want to yield the string `'none'` instead of the actual `None` object when the user calls `next`, you can do that, but it may be a bad idea:

```
def parrot():
    val = None
    while True:
        val = yield ('none' if val is None else val)
```